# Google Drive Api - Document without authorization

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am building an app where two different users will edit the same document online, using only plain text. For this I am using the **google-api-php-client-master** hosted on github.

There are some examples, but I don't understand what I need to do to achieve my goal. The official documentation is deprecated because it reffers to a library that is not online, and all the classes have different names and ways of working.

I already got my credentials, and know how to get a list of the documents hosted on my drive account. But now I need to:

- Create new document
- Grant access to a non-google logged in user, just accessing the link

I don't expect anybody to give me a written solution, but to know where I have to start.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok im trying to do almost the same thing and this is what i know so far:

Most importantly please reffer to the docomentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference

1. There is a written example on how to create new file!( section files->insert)
2. One way to make a gdrive file public is to share it to the web via the google api. Another way is to make revision of it( section revision->update) and then publish it( by setting "published" = true in the update request).

Being aware of your requirements i gues that the publishing wont really help you achieving your goal, because it is just a revision of the document from the past and not its current state.